# Flutter Dio response null

Tags: android, flutter, dart, response, dio

Am using flutter Dio library for api calling and on registration page, after the api call for user creation the user is created on database but the response shows null.

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import '../../../services/dio_web_util.dart';
import '../models/first_page_reg_request.dart';

 

class DioClient {
  Future<Response?> userRegistration(
      {required RegisterInfoReq requestData}) async {
    Response? userData;
    try {
      Response userData =
          await WebUtil.createDio().post('/Candidate/RegisterCandidate', data: requestData);
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('User Info: ${userData}');
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx and is also not 304.
      if (e.response != null) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Dio error!');
        }
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('STATUS: ${e.response?.statusCode}');
        }
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('DATA: ${e.response?.data}');
        }
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('HEADERS: ${e.response?.headers}');
        }
      } else {
        // Error due to setting up or sending the request
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Error sending request!');
        }
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print(e.message);
        }
      }
    }
    return userData;
  }
}
```

Above code is used for the service.Here the userData is prints correct value.
But the response is stored in another page and the function call for that page is

```
Response? userData= await apiClient.userRegistration(requestData: requestBody);
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('User Info: ${userData}');
        }
```

here userData is null...

Anybody have an idea about this??

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @KaranMehta,  Yes....

Comment: >But the response is stored in another page and the function call for that page is<

Maybe that's the issue. Did you try a FutureBuilder? What State Management are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring and returning following variable

```
Response? userData;
```

but initializing and printing a new variable

```
Response userData =
```

Initialize above declared variable otherwise null will be returned from future function.